# firebase functions datasnapshot is not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run the next code in firebase functions, and it gives an error of not recognizing datasnapshot. what can cause it?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.updateVotes = functions.database.ref('travels/{travelId}/locations/{locationId}/voting/users')
.onUpdate((userVotes, context) => {
    var travelId = context.params.travelId;
    var locationId = context.params.locationId
    var sumVotes = 0;

    userVotes.forEach((userVote) => {
        sumVotes += userVote.val().userVote;

    })
    // var votes = userVotes.val();
    // for (var vote in votes) {
    //     if (votes.hasOwnProperty(vote)) {
    //         sumVotes += votes[vote].userVote;
    //     }
    // }

    return admin.database()
        .ref('travels/' + travelId + '/locations/' + locationId + '/voting')
        .update({ votes: sumVotes })

})
```

The error is:

> TypeError: userVotes.forEach is not a function at exports.updateVotes.functions.database.ref.onUpdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onUpdate` doesn't return a `DataSnapshot` it returns a [`Change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object.

You need to select the `after` or `before` property - do you want the information before the write, or after the write (Usually it's after - this is the new data in Firebase).

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.updateVotes = functions.database.ref('travels/{travelId}/locations/{locationId}/voting/users')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
    var travelId = context.params.travelId;
    var locationId = context.params.locationId
    var sumVotes = 0;

    var userVotes = change.after;

    userVotes.forEach((userVote) => {
        sumVotes += userVote.val().userVote;

    })

    return admin.database()
        .ref('travels/' + travelId + '/locations/' + locationId + '/voting')
        .update({ votes: sumVotes })

})
```